# Method expect of pexpect python module breaks when matching a string in old output

Tags: python, gdb, stdout, interactive, pexpect

I'm trying to work with gdb remotely, using pexpect. This is my current code:

```
child = pexpect.spawn("ssh root@192.168.3.10 \"gdb\"")
child.logfile = sys.stdout
child.expect("password:")
child.sendline("xxxx")
child.expect("(gdb)")
child.sendline("attach 9813")
child.expect("(gdb)")
child.sendline("info registers")
child.expect("(gdb)")
child.sendcontrol('c')
```

And this is a part of my console output:

```
(...)
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
(...)
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
(gdb) attach 9813
info registers
test@test-virtual-machine:~$
```

While I **expect** something like this:

```
(...)
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
(...)
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
(gdb) attach 9813
<Attaching...>
(gdb) info registers
<Registers info displayed...>
(gdb) <Ctrl+C is done>
test@test-virtual-machine:~$
```

So, the problem seems to be that after matching first `(gdb)` and sending first command `attach 9813`, pexpect is not expecting a second `(gdb)` line to send a new command `info registers`. It sees the first `(gdb)` again, matches it and just sends a second command **without waiting** until the first one is executed (until we are attached to a needed proccess).

How can I make it analyse only the following output? Without matching the previous output twice?
I saw a sample like this for ftp server:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ftp ftp.openbsd.org')
child.expect('(?i)name .*: ')
child.sendline('anonymous')
child.expect('(?i)password')
child.sendline('pexpect@sourceforge.net')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('cd /pub/OpenBSD/3.7/packages/i386')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('bin')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('prompt')
```

As I understand, here pexpect manages to react to `ftp>` in required order and sends commands consecutively. My code seems to be similar.

I also tried flushing stdout, it did not work.

Comment: `expect()` actually treats its argument as a regex pattern, not a simple string, so your search for the prompt the first time is probably matching in `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian`, and the second time in the bug reporting URL, or something in the elided part. Try using `expect_exact()` to do simple string matching.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I tried `expect_exact()` it did not help. But I also tried expect("(\(gdb\).*){2}") for my second cmd `info registers`, and unfortunately it works, so he matches 2 `(gdb)`. But such solution is a last resort.Do you know if it has anything to do with searchwindowsize? I tried assigning `0, 1, 2`, it does not help, and it seems that i don't get the mechanism.

Comment: I did change my `expect()` to `expect_exact()` though, it seems more fair (except for the regex I showed above).

Comment: Could anything in the part you elided (`(...)`) contain `(gdb)`? Search window size shouldn't matter here.

Comment: I guess no. Documentation says indeed that `expect` analyses a presented buffer fully each time from the beginning. Then I don't really understand how the `ftp` example works. Anyways, I had to `expect` special keywords in the commands execution output, only this way for now I can understand that the execution is finished. If I think of smth better, I will post it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDB seems to sometimes show the prompt again before any output from commands. You are matching the first prompt, sending your command, then immediately matching the 'premature' prompt before the result is displayed. This means that the Control-C at the end is sent before the result from 'info registers' is displayed, but the rest of the script appears to work.

The solution is to match any expected output before sending the next command.

Comment: This is exactly what I came up with in the end. Thank you for confirming my solution. 
I will mark this as a right one.

Comment: Googlers may find this to be of interest: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/55ce88cdc3732702139c11d1448d508eaadfcf21/gdb/count_infinite_test.py :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. Joelmatth's answer reminded me of the fix.

```
trash = child.expect([".+"])
```

The ".+" matches on the first thing it finds and helps flush everything out.